# Is it possible to withdraw a close vote?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

There are many instances where a person may be asked to edit their question to fit into the general theme of the stack  exchange website. But when one takes a long time to respond, the appropriate response would be to vote to close the question.

Also, many people realize their question is at risk of being closed, and edit it due to pressure.

But it is possible to withdraw a close vote if the questionnaire suddenly takes the appropriate action, and edits their question?

many people would go to the review page, and once they see 3 or 4 close vote, they will also be encouraged to give the last vote.

Is their a possibility of allowing people to withdraw their vote if they feel the question should no longer be closed?

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140729/why-doesnt-a-change-in-question-content-allow-users-to-revise-their-close-open

Answer (score 1):

## Unfortunately NO

It is [statusbydesign](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statusbydesign)

Read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949) by stackexchange co-owner

> declining -- you can always cast a reopen vote if the post gets
> closed.
>
> Also note that all close votes automatically expire after two days.
>
> (and for that matter reopen votes, or any other vote that attempts to
> reach a threshold -- otherwise, over an absurdly long period of time,
> say 10 years, everything would reach the threshold eventually through
> a tiny trickle of accumulated votes)